error in a python code DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found
please help me fix this error i'm a bigginer in Python
and I've converted this code from Matlab to python the i faced these errors and i dont know how to dell with it ??
7, in check_versions
module = importlib.import_module(modname)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\pro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib_init.py", line 90, in import_module
return _bootstrap.gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\pro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver_init.py", line 8, in 
from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module could not be found.
PS C:\users\pro\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages>
i installed library but same error

looks there is answer in:
Matplotlib kiwisolver import problem _cext
installing: Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable
